# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied

Tags: python, windows, file, permissions, subprocess

I am trying to call a python program with `subprocess`, but I get a permission error. I tried running PyCharm as an admin, but it doesn't help.

My code:

```
answer = subprocess.check_output("../folder python program %s %s" %(valueA, valueB), encoding = 'utf8')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/a/b/b_resolution.py", line 35, in <module>
    answer = subprocess.check_output("../folder python program %s %s" %(valueA, valueB), encoding = 'utf8')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 376, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 453, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied
```

Does someone know how I can fix this permission error?

Answer (score 6):

Although it doesn't answer the original question, this `PermissionError` also arises if you (accidentally) try to run a **directory**, instead of a **file**.

For example, any of these will raise the `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`:

```py
subprocess.check_output('.')
```

```py
subprocess.run('.')
```

where `'.'` represents the path to the current directory, as a minimal example.

On the other hand, if you try to run a **non-existent file**, you'll get a more useful `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

*Tested with python 3.10.6 on Windows and Ubuntu. On Ubuntu the examples above  raise a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.*

Answer (score 6):

close file explorer...

dumb but if you have the folder open in the explorer and you're trying to do anything to the folders/files you'll get this error

Answer (score 2):

Check the file permissions for your current user.

Right click on the file and in security you can see file permissions for users.

If you haven't permission to read file, Advanced > Select a principal then [check this doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.11/dn789205(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: The OP is trying to execute a *directory* named "../folder". Windows fails this with access denied, which in this case has nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by myself the python command comes before the path.
Like this:

```
answer = subprocess.check_output("python ../folder program %s %s" %(valueA, valueB), encoding = 'utf8')
```

But I had the problem that it says:

```
can't find '__main__' module in '../pydig'
```

Solved that aswell with writing the program name included in the path:

```
answer = subprocess.check_output("python ../folder/program %s %s" %(valueA, valueB), encoding = 'utf8')
```

Comment: With an argument list, subprocess will handle any required quoting for you, based on the assumption that the program follows VC++ command-line parsing rules, which python.exe itself certainly uses since it's built with VC++.

Comment: If you're using UTF-8 mode in 3.7+ (e.g. `python -X utf8`) or defining the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to use UTF-8, then Python will write UTF-8 to a pipe in Windows. Otherwise, by default a Python script in Windows uses the system ANSI codepage (e.g. "cp1252" in a Western Europe locale) when stdout is a pipe, in which case decoding via `encoding='utf8'` will generally fail for non-ASCII text. In Windows 10, ANSI *may* be set to UTF-8, but it's not the default setting.